# PHP Argument input

Tags: views

Is there a possibility in Views 3 to provide the Argument input by a PHP snippet? I couldn't find an option for this anywhere.

I try to get the input from a query string value. I know this is an option within Views but I don't get that working so I want to try it with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible using [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php). I have used this module with success. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows the admin account (user 1) to add fields, filters and sorts to views which use PHP code. It also supports additional accounts when the core PHP Filter module is enabled.
>
> This is the successor of [Views Custom Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_customfield) for both D6 and D7. The D6 version supports both Views 2 and Views 3.

Comment: Thanks! It's still in dev, but it works. Note that you have to select 'No argument' at the argument input and then select 'Enter initial value' (or something similar; I translated it) under 'When the argument is not available' in contextual filters.

Answer (score 2):

No need of any other additional module. 
Enable PHP filter module. 
You will be able to see some screen like this. 
[image]

Comment: It seems to me this is Views 2. I can't find option(s) in Views 3.